# MySQL:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax... near 'desc) VALUES ('Idea','Description')'"

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to get MySQL to work for my form submissions.  I am having a problem when I try to insert into a table.
When I put information into my form and click submit (in this example the information is "Idea" in one field and "Description" in the other) I get this response:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES
>   ('Idea','Description')' at line 1"

I am running a .php file from a webserver to execute this script.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("date_ideas") or die(mysql_error());
$title=$_POST['title'];
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
$desc=mysql_real_escape_string($desc);
$submit="INSERT INTO ideas (title, desc) VALUES ('$title','$desc');";

mysql_query($submit) or die(mysql_error());

echo ("Idea submitted.  Click <a href='Webroot/submit.php'>here</a> to go back and post another idea.");
?>
```

If you call an echo of the variables used it succeeds at passing through the information, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be because `desc` is a keyword in SQL. Try a different name. `desc` is used to sort results in descending order.

In general I would recommend to avoid to use reserved words for column names.

Answer (score 12):

`desc` is a reserved keyword (short for `DESCENDING` in `ORDER BY`).

Enlose it into backticks:

```
INSERT INTO ideas (title, `desc`) VALUES ('$title','$desc');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I keep forgetting which words are reserved.