# PHP MYSQL Insert Into one table from another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have tried a bunch of soultions on here an other forums but always get errors.
Here is current PHP code using hostgator and PHP 5.2

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO events (datecreated, fullname, email, title, url, picurl, desc, psw, skypeid, event) SELECT jvs.datecreated, jvs.fullname, jvs.email, jvs.title, jvs.url, jvs.picurl, jvs.desc, jvs.psw, jvs.skypeid, jvs.event FROM jvs";
if (! mysqli_query($dbh, $insert)  ||  mysqli_affected_rows($dbh) == 0)
            {
die ("<BR><BR><BR>Failed to insert data- " . mysqli_error($dbh));
            }
```

Error I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc, psw, skypeid, event) SELECT jvs.datecreated, jvs.fullname,
>   jvs.email, jvs.' at line 1

I have checked every field in both tables and the spelling is correct and the fileds are there.
The fileds are not in the same order in events table and that table has many more fields.
Thanks,
Ed

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax... near 'desc) VALUES ('Idea','Description')'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357903/mysql-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-near-desc-values-idea-des)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC` is a MySQL Reserved keyword. You should escape with `backtick`, eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName(......, `desc`, .....)
SELECT ...
```

- [MySQL Reserved keyword List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thought to myself _who is JW, with 46k that I've never seen before?_ But you're Kuya John/John Woo. :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it's been a habit to change my name and pass every 30 days. I don't know why. Maybe I'm sick. haha!

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. Glad I asked here or I would have spent many more hours with this.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** See at **desc**, desc is a reserved word and readed as statement and you must add backtick to it.

**2.** You must add seperator between two query (`INSERT INTO` and `SELECT`)

**3.** And where is your `VALUES`, `INSERT INTO` must include a `VALUES`

And the fix code is:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO events (`datecreated`, `fullname`, `email`, `title`, `url`, `picurl`, `desc`, `psw`, `skypeid`, `event`) VALUES('datecreated', 'fullname', 'email', 'title', 'url', 'picurl', 'desc', 'psw', 'skypeid', 'event');
SELECT jvs.datecreated, jvs.fullname, jvs.email, jvs.title, jvs.url, jvs.picurl, jvs.desc, jvs.psw, jvs.skypeid, jvs.event FROM jvs";
if (! mysqli_query($dbh, $insert)  ||  mysqli_affected_rows($dbh) == 0){
   die ("<BR><BR><BR>Failed to insert data- " . mysqli_error($dbh));
}
```

Comment: This is inserting from one table to another so values are not used. Looks like you backticked everything. I guess that would be a good idea to be safe.
Just putting the backticks around desc solved everything.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried to mark yours as accepted but it wouldn't without unchecking the other answer. He answered first so I gave the accept to him.

Comment: i'm sorry ..., i don't know :)